# Should "Comments disabled on..." seen in deleted posts be a functional link?

Tags: bug

This is not asking about whether [Comments should be disabled in locked/deleted questions/review queues](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11148/add-comment-requires-50-reputation-in-review), a topic that has been raised before, but a more minor issue on the link-behavior that seems to be intended for that text, at least appearing [in the context of deleted posts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077819/functional-equation-functional-square-root).  (Viewing the HTML element shows a bit of Javascript `add-link` code.)

It would make sense to have it function as a link to a Review Queue FAQ (e.g. about when Comments are appropriate in reviews) or perhaps to a [Meta.SE discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198951/why-are-comments-now-disabled-on-the-review-queue) on the policy's history.

This might be a bug, or it might be some planned or implemented functionality that has been temporarily suspended pending improvement.

---

Although the link functionality is "disabled", the Javascript element provides this "hover text" on mouse-over:

> Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements.  Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks".

This is the same hint provided for the normal add-comment link.  A [Meta.SE Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194691/could-you-remove-or-change-the-add-comment-hint-from-deleted-answers) last year criticized this "hint" as not helpful and called for its removal.